# How can I make elasticsearch-setup-passwords work for self signed certificate?

Tags: elasticsearch

I deploy Elasticsearch 7.15 on K8S with default configuration. After launching the cluster, I need to setup the username password by running `bin/elasticsearch-setup-passwords`. But it gives me this error:

```
SSL connection to https://10.0.2.26:9200/_security/_authenticate?pretty failed: No subject alternative names matching IP address 10.0.2.26 found
Please check the elasticsearch SSL settings under xpack.security.http.ssl.
```

since the certificate is self signed. How can I setup the configuration to support this? Or is there a way to skip the certificate check?

Answer (score 0):

add "elasticsearch.yaml" 中 "xpack.security.http.ssl.verification_mode: certificate"

Comment: add "xpack.security.http.ssl.verification_mode: certificate" to the file "elasticsearch.yaml"

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).